# "glm::translate" outputs a matrix with incorrect values

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2017, glm-math

I took a sample code to test the glm::translate function:

```
glm::vec4 vec(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glm::mat4 trans;
trans = glm::translate(trans, glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
vec = trans * vec;
std::cout << vec.x << ", " << vec.y << ", " << vec.z << std::endl;
```

It outputs the following:

```
-4.29497e+08, -4.29497e+08, -4.29497e+08
```

instead of the expected `2, 1, 0`

What is the possible cause and what can I do about it?

(Should I search for the flaw outside *this* piece of code?)

Comment: What makes you think the correct answer is `2, 1, 0`? Have you stepped through the code with a debugger? MS VS 2017 has a great graphical debugger built in.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. With the code above, I get the output `2, 1, 0`.

Comment: Can't reproduce.  What are the components of `trans` immediately after construction?  I seem to recall an older version of `glm` whose `mat4` default constructor left the components uninitialized rather than as the identity matrix.

Comment: @G.M. Yes, that was the problem. Thanks. Initializing it as an identity matrix has helped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
-4.29497e+08
```

This looks like uninitialised memory, which would lead me to believe the flaw lies in:

```
glm::mat4 trans;
```

You have not initialised the matrix, but have performed an arithmetic operation on it. You cannot assume that a constructor will initialise it's memory, so change to:

```
glm::mat4 trans(1.0f);
```

And that should fix the problem.

This *may* not show up in all development environments, as, for example, debug mode in VS has some safeguards to prevent this, but it will show up in release mode.

Simply put: Practice RAII: Resource Acquisition Is Initialisation. At the very least, zero the memory, as when the memory is reallocated, it will be set to whatever it's previous value was when it was last released.

Comment: Just for the records: In newer versions of glm, the default constructor always creates an identity matrix.

Comment: Maybe so, but if you follow good programming practices, you should also use RAII (Resource Acquisition Is Initialisation). uninitialised stuff accounts for a huge number of bugs, so getting into this habit makes for more stable code.

Comment: @BDL I used the latest version of glm but I still get the same issue. Is there any configuration I need to set to enable the default construction?

Comment: @YuanMa: If you have a new question, feel free to ask one (like: "I have problem X and found answer Y. But unfortunately this doesnt work for me because of Z." Don't forget to mention compiler/OS and provide a minimal example of your not-working code). You can than ping me here and I might have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your translation matrix

```
glm::mat4 trans(1);
```