# How to make 2D Zoom in OpenGL(GLFW, glad)?

Tags: c++, opengl, zooming, glfw, glm-math

I'm trying to implement a simple paint program and now I have a problem with zoom, I can't understand how to do it? I tried to adapt the code from [here](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Camera) to myself, but it did not work, I just get a black screen. What my problem?

**Not using glut or glew!**

**Here my camera code:**

.h

```
class Camera2d
{
public:
    Camera2d(const glm::vec3& pos = glm::vec3(0.f, 0.f, 0.f),
         const glm::vec3& up  = glm::vec3(0.f, 1.f, 0.f));
   //~Camera2d();
    void        setZoom(const float& zoom);
    float       getZoom()       const noexcept;
    glm::mat4   getViewMatrix() const noexcept;
    void        mouseScrollCallback(const float& yOffset);
protected:
    void        update();
private:
    // Camera zoom
    float       m_zoom;
    // Euler Angles
    float       m_yaw;
    float       m_pitch;
public:
    // Camera Attributes
    glm::vec3   position;
    glm::vec3   worldUp;
    glm::vec3   front;
    glm::vec3   up;
    glm::vec3   right;
};
```

.cpp

```
Camera2d::Camera2d(
    const glm::vec3& pos /* = glm::vec3(0.f, 0.f, 0.f) */,
    const glm::vec3& up  /* = glm::vec3(0.f, 1.f, 0.f) */
    )
    : m_zoom(45.f)
    , m_yaw(-90.f)
    , m_pitch(0.f)
    , position(pos)
    , worldUp(up)
    , front(glm::vec3(0.f, 0.f, -1.f))
{
    this->update();
}
void Camera2d::setZoom(const float& zoom)
{
    this->m_zoom = zoom;
}
float Camera2d::getZoom() const noexcept
{
    return this->m_zoom;
}
glm::mat4 Camera2d::getViewMatrix() const noexcept
{
    return glm::lookAt(this->position, this->position + this->front, this->up);
}

void Camera2d::mouseScrollCallback(const float& yOffset)
{
    if (m_zoom >= 1.f && m_zoom <= 45.f)
        m_zoom -= yOffset;
    else if (m_zoom <= 1.f)
        m_zoom = 1.f;
    else if (m_zoom >= 45.f)
        m_zoom = 45.f;
}

void Camera2d::update()
{
    // Calculate the new Front vector
    glm::vec3 _front;
    _front.x = cos(glm::radians(this->m_yaw)) * cos(glm::radians(this->m_pitch));
    _front.y = sin(glm::radians(this->m_pitch));
    _front.z = cos(glm::radians(this->m_pitch)) * sin(glm::radians(this->m_yaw));
    this->front = glm::normalize(_front);
    // Also re-calculate the Right and Up vector
    this->right = glm::normalize(glm::cross(this->front, this->worldUp));      // Normalize the vectors, because their length gets closer to 0 the more     you look up or down which results in slower movement.
    this->up = glm::normalize(glm::cross(this->right, this->front));
}
```

and in main i try smth like this in render loop

```
    // pass projection matrix to shader
    glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(camera.getZoom()),
            static_cast<float>(WIDTH) / static_cast<float>(HEIGHT),
            0.1f,
            10000.f);
    shaderProg.setMat4("projecton", projection);
    // camera view transformation
    glm::mat4 view = camera.getViewMatrix();
    shaderProg.setMat4("view", view);

    here i have just 1 model its my white bg-texture
    glm::mat4 model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(0.f, 0.f, 0.f));
    model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(0.f), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.3f, 0.5f));
    shaderProg.setMat4("model", model);
```

All code on github: [here](https://github.com/Kovacz/SimplePaint/blob/master/Paint/src/main.cpp)

Comment: did you get a black screen before you implemented the zoom? are you sure the black screen is a result of modifying the field of view?

Comment: actually before i have black screen too, but before i can change bg color by my texture (when i press on keyboard key "N") and before i can draw lines :D

Comment: discovering this problem, i find one interesting thing, if i change in my vertex shader gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(aPos, 1.0f) on just gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0f) all f*cking working, so i think smth here wrong???

Comment: Why do you use perspective projection for 2D task? I would use orthographic. And w/o model transform (you have only one model anyway). BTW, what OS you working on?

Comment: `glm::mat4 model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(0.f, 0.f, 0.f));` You must initialize `model` before using it at glm::translate. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47178228/glmtranslate-outputs-a-matrix-with-incorrect-values)

Comment: I'm using macOS, about orthographic, so I need use glm::ortho?

Comment: Ok, I init model, it didn't help

Comment: see [Zooming graphics based on current mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37269366/2521214)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're working in 2D, forget about the camera, forget about projection, forget about following OpenGL tutorials, they're aimed at 3D graphics.

What you need is just a rectangle to fill your screen. Start with the vertices at the the corners of the screen, starting from the top-left corner and moving counterclockwise: (-1,1,0) (-1,-1,0) (1,-1,0) (1,1,0). Forget about Z, you're working in 2D.

You draw on a texture, and the texture coordinates are (0,1) (0,0) (1,0) (1,1), same order as above. Zooming is now just a matter of scaling the rectangle. You have a matrix to determine the scale and one to determine the position. Forget about rotations, front vectors and all that stuff. In the vertex shader you scale and then translate the vertices as usual, in this order. Done.

To interact for example you can have mouse wheel up increasing the scale factor and mouse wheel down decreasing it. Hold click and move the mouse to change the (x,y) position. Again forget about Z. Throw those values into the vertex shader and do the usual transformations.

Comment: Hi, thx for answer, but I want to clarify a bit, I need in vertex shader scale my position of screen or texture coords? And how to connect it with the mouse?

Comment: @Azazel-San only the position. Texture coordinates must stay untouched. To learn how to process input in GLFW, read the documentation, it has everything you need to know: [https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/input_guide.html](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/input_guide.html)

Comment: Thx for help, but now when I'm zooming old shapes not redraw, how I can fix that without using glClearColor and glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)?