# OpenGL glm rotate model around a point issue

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation, quaternions, glm-math

I have a model and some helper cubes which are located on its axes, three on each axis for transformations, I used them for rotate the model around its local axes.

[image]

I want to make those cubes rotate around the model center with its rotation so I translate them to the model center, rotate them by the same angle on the same axis the translate them back.
This is the code:

```
//Rotation around X axis
GLfloat theta=glm::radians(xoffset);
glm::quat Qx(glm::angleAxis(theta, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)));
glm::mat4 rotX = glm::mat4_cast(Qx);
pickedObject->Transform(rotX);//Multiply the model matrix by the transformation matrix
glm::vec3 op(pickedObject->getMatrix()[3]);//model position
for(TransformationHelper* h:pickedObject->GetTransformationHelpers()){//the small cubes
     glm::mat4 m,it,t;
     glm::vec3 hp(h->getMatrix()[3]);//the cube position
     t=glm::translate(m,op);//m is a unit matrix
     it=glm::translate(m,-op);
     m=t*rotX*it;
     h->Transform(m);
}
```

The result is unexpected

[image]

Update:
after updating the translation matrix I got this result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The translation is in the wrong direction; the correct offset should be `hp-op`, i.e. the matrix `t` should restore the cube's position after rotating.

```
 t=glm::translate(glm::mat(1.f),hp-op);
```

Also there is no need to use `inverse` since it is costly (and numerically less stable):

```
 it=glm::translate(glm::mat(1.f),op-hp);
```

(Note: here `translate` was called with an explicitly constructed identity matrix. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47178228/glmtranslate-outputs-a-matrix-with-incorrect-values) for a similar problem. See [here](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/issues/809#issuecomment-417351401) for why this is necessary.)

Comment: I corrected the translation matrix but the cubes translated away from its locations. I added a picture.

Comment: The `op` is not at the world origin so `(op-hp)` will translate the cub to the model's origin

Comment: `virtual void Transform(const glm::mat4& m){
        modelMatrix=modelMatrix*m;
    }`

Comment: It multiplies the model matrix by the transformation matrix

Comment: @MohamedMoussa I see; your implementation of `Transform` is different to what I expected. I'll update.

Comment: The `op` is the center I want to rotate cubes around and the `hp` is the cube position so when i change the to be as you post the cubes fly away

Comment: All matrices are in the global axes, so either`op` and `hp` are in the same coordination

Comment: What I meant was post-multiplying the `modelMatrix` by a transformation `m` will apply `m` in the model's *local* basis, not the global. This makes e.g. global translations inconvenient as you would need to invert the model matrix; the offset `hp - op` needs to be applied in the global basis.

Comment: I understood that multiplying the `modelMatrix` by the transformation matrix will apply the transformation in the local space that makes sense, but i am confused about using the inverse for solving this issue.

Comment: The offset `hp - op` needs to be applied in the global basis, but `Transform` can only apply transformations (directly) in the local basis. You need the inverse of `modelMatrix` to convert between the two representations, which is costly and inaccurate. It's better to implement an alternative which pre-multiplies instead.

Comment: I solved it with help of your answer, I made the cubes in the object space not in the world space so any transformations happen to the object will apply to all its children